# in hadoop, how to parse log files in order to obtain multiple information not just one information like wordcount?

Tags: hadoop

I am wondering how hadoop handle log file parsing if we need to calculate not just one simple metric (e.g. the most popular word) but many metrics(e.g. ALL the following: average height break down into gender, top 10 sites break down into phone types, top word break down into adults/kids)?

Without using hadoop, a typical distributed solution I can think is: split logs into different machines using hash, etc; 
each machine parses its own log files and calculate different metrics for these log files. The results can be stored as SQL, XML, or some other format in files. Then a master machine parses these intermediate files, aggregates these metrics and stored the final results to another file.

Using hadoop, how to obtain the final results? All the examples I saw are very simple cases, like count words.

I just cannot figure out how hadoop mapreducer will cooperate to aggregate the intermediate files intelligently to final result. I thought maybe my mapper should save intermediate files somewhere and my reducer should parse the intermediate files to get the final results. I must be wrong since I do not see any benefit if my mapper and reducer are implemented in this way.

It is said the format of map and reduce should be:
map: (K1, V1) → list(K2, V2)
combine: (K2, list(V2)) → list(K2, V2)
reduce: (K2, list(V2)) → list(K3, V3)

In summery, how to design my mapper and reducer code (suppose using python, other language is also fine.) Can anybody answer my question or provide a link for me to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start thinking on how to solve challenges in a MR way. Here ([1](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025122.do), [2](http://lintool.github.io/MapReduceAlgorithms/)) are some resources. These have got some of the MR algorithms which can be implemented in any language.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at the books. but anyway it seems the original non-hadoop system has to be rewritten.